# How to auto gen. custom post type values in other custom post type in url?

Tags: urls

I have created two custom post types (CPT) say books and reviews. Now how can i auto generated a reviews page for a specific book title??.

What i have done so far i made a review page (page-reviews.php) which displays the reviews based on a book's $id. 
In CPT "reviews" there is a dropdown menu with id's corresponding the book title.

I thought of something like `mydomain.com/books/{title-book}/reviews`

But how can i auto generate this url path to be recognized and how do i get the book's $id in reviews (page-reviews.php)

should i alter the 
`'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'reviews' ),`

Regards,

Comment: I would suggest that where you have a review of a book, the book post be the parent post of that review. How you would set up the URLs and archives however is up to whoever answers the question

Comment: @TomJNowell tx, i am trying  `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'books/%postname%/reviews' ), ` which looks like what i want but i get a 404

Comment: You won't be able to do this inside the `register_post_type` call, that URL is for the location of the archive and review posts, not an archive of all review posts with a parent or link to another post of another type also in the URL. You will need custom rewrite rules and archives.